# How to grab a property object from DB

Tags: database, image, object, model, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some doubts, maybe newbie doubts but I just got into ASP.NET MVC 4
Basically I would like to know the correct way of grabbing details of an Object inside a model.
In this case Image inside Contractor.

Model:

```
public class Contractor {

    [Key]
    public int ContractorID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Image Avatar { get; set; }
    }

public class Image {

    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string File_name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte[] File_data { get; set; }


}


public class DATACRUD : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Contractor> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private DATACRUD db = new DATACRUD();

public ActionResult GetContractorAvatar(int id)
{
        Contractor contractor = db.Contractors.Find(id);

        if (contractor == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Image avatar = contractor.Avatar;
```

---

Problem 1)

avatar == null, but is not suppose to be because when I created the object Contractor, I added the image sucessfully (I checked in the DB and it is there)

The solution I'm seeing is instead of having Image property in Contractor.cs model, I would just put a string property with the image key.

---

Problem 2)

Even If could grab the image key like I said in the previous problem, when I pass my mouse in Debug mode over 
private DATACRUD db = new DATACRUD ();

db.Images is also empty...

---

```
        return File(avatar.File_data, "image");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't defined your `Image` navigation property as `virtual`, you will have to eager load the `Image` when loading a `Contractor`:

```
db.Contractors.Include("Avatar").SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContractorID == id);
```

OR

```
// using System.Data.Entity;
db.Contractors.Include(c => c.Avatar).SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContractorID == id);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the information, but why should I have a foreigner key of Contractor in Image? I only access Images through Contractor or Company. But I don't need the oposite

Comment: Hey I did not defined a foreigner key in image but I just tried the eager load like you said in the last lines of code and it works ;) Thank you very much

Comment: @user1837862 My apologies, I thought that is how your model was defined.